# Setting up an Odoo 12 developer environment, Issues with Werkzeug version

Tags: python, odoo, urllib2, werkzeug, socketserver

I'm attempting to set up an Odoo 12 instance with a Python 3.7 virtualenv on Ubuntu version 18.04 using Pycharm. I keep getting issues related to Werkzeug as follows:

If I use the desired version of werkzueg written in the requirements.txt file(Werkzeug==0.11.15) I get this error. I think this error comes from werkzueg's version not supporting Python 3.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2700, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import dump_options_header, dump_header, generate_etag, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_options_header' from 'werkzeug.http' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_http_list' from 'urllib.request' (/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2700, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import dump_options_header, dump_header, generate_etag, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_options_header' from 'werkzeug.http' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I use the most current version of werkzueg (Werkzeug==1.0.1) I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/alexvining/Documents/Odoo Dev Env/Odoo 12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 32, in <module>
    import werkzeug.contrib.sessions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 61, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 58, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 61, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'

Original exception was:

  File "/home/alexvining/Documents/Odoo Dev Env/Odoo 12/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 32, in <module>
    import werkzeug.contrib.sessions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 61, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sorry that I had to shorten the error logs, stack overflow was giving me an error saying the message looked like spam.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`werkzeug.contrib` was removed in v1.0.0.

Changing the requirements.txt entry to

```
werkzeug==0.16.1
```

will work.